# algorithm for ai to chase player in straight line?

Tags: java, algorithm, path, libgdx

I am making a game in libgdx(java) where squares chase the main player. I can't figure out how to make the squares move in a straight line directly to the player  at a constant speed. this means i want the squares to travel the same distance every second. I make a variable and set it equal to `chasePattern1`. `saidvariable[0]` is added to the enemies `x` value, and `saidvariable[1]` is added to the enemies `y` value.

```
private float[] chasePattern1(float enemy_x,float enemy_y,float speed){
    float[] returnvalue={0,0};

    if(enemy_x>mainsquare.getX()){
        returnvalue[0]=-1*speed;
    }
    if(enemy_x<mainsquare.getX()){
        returnvalue[0]=speed;///does float work?no
    }
    if(enemy_y>mousey){
        returnvalue[1]=-1*speed;
    }
    if(enemy_y<mousey){
        returnvalue[1]=speed;
    }
    return returnvalue;
}
```

Comment: That's easy. The algorithm that determines distance is based on time, so pass the same elapsed time to the move...but you'll be moving more often than once a second (I hope) so you'll probably send some number of milliseconds to the method.

Comment: Throw in the relevant code and point out where you're stuck, and then presto, you have an answerable question.

Comment: this is what im using right now... dont think it helps though

Comment: I can't really tell what you're doing and if it's based on the library you're using but I think the best option is to determine theta (the angle between their headings).

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `d` is the distance between the player and a square, `v` is the velocity that you want the squares to move at, `(x1,y1)` is the position of the player and `(x0,y0)` is the position of the square, then

```
vx = (x1 - x0) * v / d
vy = (y1 - y0) * v / d
```

where `vx` and `vy` are the values that you need to add to the square's coordinates every second.

#### Edit:

You can view it like this: If you want to travel from your position to the destination `d` "points" with a speed of `v`, it would take you `t=d/v` moves.

Now, the distance you have to travel horizontally is `x1-x0` and the distance vertically is `y1-y0`, if you want to travel both distances in `t` moves, you need to divide each distance in `t` pieces and that's the speed for each component (`x` and `y`).  When you divide `x1-x0` for `t`, you get that value, same for `y`

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: But of course this makes the square move much faster on the diagonal than on horizontal or vertical lines, because you're moving a greater distance of you move both in x and y direction at a time, than if you're just moving in x, or just moving in y direction. That's why the other answer is more correct (but potentially slower)

Comment: You always travel at `v` speed, no matter which direction.  And actually, both answers calculate the same values

Comment: Sorry, looks like you're right. Misinterpreted your expressions.

Comment: is      vx = (x1 - x0)  / d* v and 
vy = (y1 - y0)  / d* v the same as vx = (x1 - x0) * v / d
and vy = (y1 - y0) * v / d

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want to do conceptually.

You want to create a vector in the direction your AI is going to move. That would be a vector in the direction connecting the AI to the player. Then, scale the vector so that it has length 1. Then multiply that vector by the constant speed of the AI.

Here's some pseudocode

```
AI_SPEED = 5
v = [ player.x - ai.x , player.y - ai.y ]
len = sqrt( v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y )
dir = [ v.x / len , v.y / len ]
movement = [ dir.x * AI_SPEED , dir.y * AI_SPEED ]
ai.x += movement.x;
ai.y += movement.y;
```

Comment: The immediate "problem", perhaps only potentially, is that sqrt is ssslllloooowww. Say it really slow....

Comment: I doubt it is an issue in a simple game, but if it becomes an issue, you can always approximate sqrt using precomputed tables.